# Set Lottie animation to UIBarbuttonitem in navigation bar swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, lottie

Am try to set lottie animation in Navigation bar button of UInavigation controller and i don't know how to set animation to UIbarButtons

Comment: Use a custom view for `UIBarButtonItem` and set animation on the custom view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make use of `UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourView)`

```
//Initialise a Lottie view with frame
let customAnimationView = AnimationView(name: "yourLottieFileName")
customAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

//Do your configurations
customAnimationView.loopMode = .loop
customAnimationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore

//Add a tap gesture
customAnimationView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourViewTapped(_:)))) //Declare an @objc function to handle your view's tap 
//And play
customAnimationView.play()

//Initilise a bar button with this custom Lottie view and use it
yourBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customAnimationView)
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(yourBarButton, animated: true)
```

Tested this code and it works fine for me.